# Is there a native version of the Source engine on Linux?

Tags: wine, steam

I'm sick of using Wine because its full of bugs and lags a lot. I want to play Half-life on Linux natively. I have it on my Steam account. My brother says that there is a Linux version. Where can i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valve is working on both [Steam and Source Engine's ports for Linux](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=valve_linux_dampfnudeln&num=1), but they are still in production (but [could be out this year](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTExMzA)). However the first source game they'll launch is most probably Left 4 Dead 2.

I'd love to see older games like Half-Life ported as well.